# Netty server - slow consumer over TCP

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I'm writing a TCP server using Netty v4. The server will handle multiple connections from clients, and stream data to them.

I want to be able to detect when a client is consuming data at a slow ratio. I basically want to avoid the TCP buffers to get full just because a client is slow!

It's basically what ZeroMQ does (called "Slow Subscriber Detection (Suicidal Snail Pattern)"). How can that be done using Netty?

My current code is (I'll just show the server setup):

```
      ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
      b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
          .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
          .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1000)
          .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
          .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
              ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
              p.addLast(new Handler());
            }
          });

      ChannelFuture f = b.bind(8000).sync();
      f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
```

Is that wha the `SO_BACKLOG` option does? It says it's for connections being queued, but I'm interested in packets being queued for a specific connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you might do this is to use [WriteBufferWaterMark](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/WriteBufferWaterMark.html)s. Quoting from the javadoc:

> WriteBufferWaterMark is used to set low water mark and high water mark
>   for the write buffer. If the number of bytes queued in the write
>   buffer exceeds the high water mark, Channel.isWritable() will start to
>   return false. If the number of bytes queued in the write buffer
>   exceeds the high water mark and then dropped down below the low water
>   mark, Channel.isWritable() will start to return true again.

Setting the appropriate water marks on your child channel [configs](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelConfig.html#setWriteBufferWaterMark(io.netty.channel.WriteBufferWaterMark)), a slow consumer will mark the channel not-writable for "long" periods of time versus snappy consumers. Therefore, listening on channel write-ability state changes and tracking the amount of time channels are non-writable should identify slow consumers and the relative severity of the backlog, and then you can disconnect a client if their sluggishness reaches some threshold.

Comment: You can use `Channel.isWritable()` even without changing the watermarks. They have default values. The `Selector` will cease to report OP_WRITE when the socket send buffer fills.

Comment: @Nicholas great thanks a lot. A very simple version would be: `if(!ctx.channel().isWritable()) ctx.channel().close();` right? Is that safe to do?

Comment: @Nicholas you didn't answer my last question, but I still think your answer is helpful :P thanks! I'll accept it!

Comment: @Will That would work but you might find it's a bit severe. A little bit of network congestion might incorrectly cast a consumer for termination. I was thinking a configurable number of "not-writable" events in the last n seconds would allow you to fine tune your tolerance for temporary traffic backups. But uh... I haven't actually implemented this, except in mind....

Answer (score 0):

> Is that what the SO_BACKLOG option does?

Is what what the SO_BACKLOG option does?

> It says it's for connections being queued

Correct.

> but I'm interested in packets being queued for a specific connection

So you aren't interested in SO_BACKLOG.

Comment: I'm interested in an option to cut off (disconnect) clients when they're too slow consuming messages from the TCP buffer. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

In case your only goal is to avoid buffer overflow (back pressure) this approach would be enough :

```
if (ctx.channel().isWritable()) {
    ctx.writeAndFlush(msg);
}
```

Comment: What if the `msg` is big enough to fill the buffer and the consumer is slow? Won't that end up blocking the thread?